# Send touch events from touchpad?

Tags: synaptics, multi-touch, libinput

I was wondering if you can configure a synaptics or libinput powered touchpad to also expose its touch events, so that an API such as Xinput2.2 can consume them. Using `evtest` I can see that five fingers will generate what you would expect, each finger outputs its own positions, however listing the devices via Xinput2.2 displays that the touchpad does not have a touchclass and it won't generate TouchBegin/Update/End events.

Comment: So this is the question about "Xinput2.2". Kernel generates events as expected. Is "Xinput2.2" used in Ubuntu?

Comment: Xinput2 is the interface used by gtk, qt etc on ubuntu to interface with the drivers. The question refers to how it may be possible to configure the ubuntu drivers for libinput/synaptics to what I would think is just handing over the touch events to that interface so that applications can consume it.

Comment: That is not about libinput or synapics. These user space drivers get kernel events that you can see in evdev. Based on these events they interpret them as gestures. kernel events are available to all user space applications. Nothing is to configure.

Comment: To my understanding the user space drivers act as intermediary from the xserver, taking in the raw events as seen in evtest, and doing a translation before then forwarding new events to the GUI applications running under X11 in the case of Xinput2.2. The problem now is that the drivers only appear to forward a subset of those events.

Comment: User space drivers don't "forward" kernel events. They take raw kernel events, interpret them and create other events like "tap", "scroll", etc. And it is true that not all kernel events are used. Applications can read raw events too if needed.

Comment: Oh okay, thank you. What I meant to say then is that the user space drivers are configured to not create events for the touch events they receive from the hardware.

Comment: If you look into evdev output, you'll see that raw events are a "touch", "untouch", finger coordinates, finger width. That's it. They are generated by a kernel driver. You can interpret them as you wish. This is the API between kernel and user space.

Comment: If possible (this was the intent of the question), I would like the userspace driver to interpret and generate these events for me, so that applications that I didn't write myself will get to access these events. The applications are listening for Touch events via Xinput2.2, but the userspace drivers appear to only output the interpreted mouse events.

Comment: You'll need to write your own user space driver or patch the existing one to interpret events "for you". Or teach your applications to read kernel events directly.

Comment: alright, if you know that both synaptics and libinput don't support such configuration, could you post your last comment as an answer? I'll mark the question as answered then